# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Xcode cannot find videoURL from bundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

Xcode tells me " Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". when I am trying to play a video. I clearly have the video in my Xcode file as shown below but it tells me it can't find my video. Please will really need some help.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if your file is added to your target, under “Copy Resources” phase in Build Phases

Comment: @andrehungaro Thank you that was the problem! I forgot to add to target. Fixed!

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use

```
if let videoUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"video",withExtension:"mp4") { --- }
```

And verify target memberShip is ticked for the asset **video.mp4**

Comment: Thanks! The problem was I forgot to add to target. Thanks guys!